# Pandas time series plot - setting custom ticks

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am creating a general-purpose average_week aggregation and plot tool using pandas. Everything works fine (I'd be glad to receive comments on that, too), but the ticks: as I "fake" dates, I want to replace the whole set of ticks with the homebrewed (I already received some questions regarding January 1 on the timeline).

Yet, it seems that pandas overwrite all the ticks, no matter what I pass after. I was able to add ticks I want - yet I can't find how to erase pandas ones.

```
def averageWeek(df, ax, tcol='ts', ccol='id', label=None, treshold=0, 
normalize=True, **kwargs):
    '''calculate average week on ts'''

    s = df[[tcol, ccol]].rename(columns={tcol:'ts',ccol:'id'}) # rename to convention

    s = df[['id', 'ts']].set_index('ts').resample('15Min', how='count').reset_index()
    s['id'] = s['id'].astype(float)


    s['ts'] = s.ts.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(year=2015,month=1, 
                                                              day=(x.weekday()+1), 
                                                              hour=x.hour, 
                                                              minute = x.minute))

    s = s.groupby(['ts']).agg('mean')


    if s.id.sum() >= treshold:
        if normalize:
            s = 1.0*s/s.sum()
        else:
            pass

        if label:
            s.rename(columns={'id':label}, inplace=1)

        s.plot(ax=ax, legend=False, **kwargs);



    else:
        print name, 'didnt pass treshhold:', s[name].sum()
        pass

    return g

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,6))


aw = averageWeek(LMdata, ax=frame, label='Lower Manhattan', alpha=1, lw=1)
x = [datetime.datetime(year=2015, month=1, day=i) for i in range(1,8)]
labels = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']



frame.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])

plt.xlabel('Average week')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give a sample dataframe and a minimum working code? `set_xticks([])` works fine for me clearing in a simpler example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that there are actually two kinds of tick labels involved in this: major and minor ticklabels, at major and minor ticks. You want to clear both of them. For example, if `ax` is the axis in question, the following will work:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([],minor=False) # the default
ax.set_xticklabels([],minor=True)
```

You can then set the ticklabels and tick locations that you want.